# Why does this map retrieval produce a NPE?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Consider this class:

```
public class TestMap extends HashMap<String, Float> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMap tm = new TestMap();
        tm.put("A", 0F);
        tm.put("B", null);

        String[] keys = new String[]{"A", "B"};

        for (String key : keys) {
            System.out.println(key);
            Float foo = (tm == null ? 0F : tm.get(key));
//          Float foo = tm.get(key);
            System.out.println(foo);
        }       
    }
}
```

A NullPointerException is produced on the line `Float foo =...` during the second iteration of the loop:

```
A
0.0
B
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestMap.main(TestMap.java:14)
```

If I replace the existing line with the commented line immediately below it works as expected, assigning foo = null. Why is the behavior different in these two cases?

Comment: I'd declare `final TestMap tm = ...` and forgo the `tm == null` check.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value for key "B" is null.  But the return type of your conditional expression is a float (primitive) due to you using the literal `0F`, not a Float (wrapper), so the value has to be autounboxed (to a primitive) and then autoboxed (back to an object).  This results in the NPE.

Compare to what happens when you use

```
Float foo = (tm == null ? Float.valueOf(0f) : tm.get(key));
```

As an added explanation, here's what your conditional is doing (showing explicit boxing):

```
Float foo;
float conditionalResult;

if ( tm == null ) {
    conditionalResult = 0F;
} else {
    conditionalResult = tm.get(key).floatValue(); //this throws the NPE
}
foo = Float.valueOf(conditionalResult);
```

[JLS 15.25](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#290293) defines what the return type of a conditional operator will be.  It's quite complex, and I find it easier to learn through experimentation :-).

Comment: That's tricky - didn't expect the conditional to alter the return type of the second clause based on the first... thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, that part can be confusing at first.  Java needs to know statically (at compile time) what the return type is, so it needs to choose a single return type that works for both possibilities.